# Samyang AE 8 F3.5 CS II fish-eye with SFH-14 filter holder

Tags: fisheye, samyang

Is there any chance to work together lens and filter holder:
- Samyang AE 8 F3.5 CS II fish-eye
- Samyang SFH-14?